# Type props for a context provider wrapping <App/>?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state, wrapper, children

I am defining a context provider to wrap my `<App/>` component like this:

```
// index.ts
ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <AuthProvider>
        <App />
      </AuthProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I got the context provider definiton working by passing `{children}` deconstructed from props with the `React.ReactNode` type, and the return wraps the children between two `<AuthContext.Provider>` tags like this:

```
// src/context/AutContext.ts

// Context definition
const AuthContext = React.createContext<{currentUser: User} | undefined>(undefined);

// Context provider wrapper definition:
const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const { currentUser } = useCurrentUse();
  
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }}>
        {children} // <- note the different ways of passing children to the Provider
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );  
  };
```

But I am trying to streamline the code by reducing `<AuthContext.Provider/>` to a one liner, which right now I have working passing `props` regularly, but with type `any`:

```
// Context provider wrapper definition (one liner variant):
const AuthProvider = (props: any) => { // <- any type. props instead of destructured {children}
  const { currentUser } = useCurrentUser();

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }} {...props} />; // <- spread one liner
};
```

Any idea of how should I type `props` in the second variant? I have tried inferring it but the result does not work (and is a mess), and using `React.ReactNode` as a type only works with `{children}`, not with the entire `props`.

In `@types/react` I have found a `ProviderProps<T>` which might be the solution, but if it is, I still don't know what to replace `T` with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L330) for `ProviderProps<T>` the generic `T` is used to type the `value` property.

This means you would provide the same `T` as provided to `React.createContext<T>()`.

Simple Method:

```
// We know from inspecting the ProviderProps type that it has two properties
// The first property value is not to be passed in.
// The second property children is an optional set of react nodes.
// The React.FunctionComponent type with no generic added only has a prop of type 
// children?: React.ReactNode.
// This will make the props of AuthProvider compatible with the props of AuthContext.Provider.
const AuthProvider: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {
    const { currentUser } = useCurrentUser();
  
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }} {...props} />
    );
};
```

More Complex Method:

```
type ContextValue = {currentUser: User} | undefined;

// depending on your version of typescript Omit might not like types with generics
// the work around for this is to create a wrapping type around Omit to trick it into
// thinking that it is getting a type it approves of.
// If this does not effect your version of typescript just use:
// Omit<ProviderProps<ContextValue>, 'value'>
type OmitValue<T> = Omit<T, 'value'>

const AuthContext = React.createContext<ContextValue>(undefined);

// We do not control the type ProviderProps, this may change in the future.
// To give better future proofing we can use the ProviderProp type and remove the
// properties we do not want to be changed (value in this case) using Omit.
// This means that any additional properties added to ProviderProps in the future
// will be valid for AuthProvider, but at this point in time it will just be
// children.
const AuthProvider: React.FunctionComponent<OmitValue<ProviderProps<ContextValue>>> = (props) => {
    const { currentUser } = useCurrentUser();
  
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }} {...props} />
    );
};
```

---

## Update

React 18 removes the default `children` property off of `React.FunctionComponent` or its proxy `React.FC`. To make the 'Simple Method' above work without type errors the new `React.PropsWithChildren` can be used.

Simple Method:

```
// We know from inspecting the ProviderProps type that it has two properties
// The first property value is not to be passed in.
// The second property children is an optional set of react nodes.
// The React.FunctionComponent type with no generic added only has a prop of type 
// children?: React.ReactNode.
// This will make the props of AuthProvider compatible with the props of AuthContext.Provider.
const AuthProvider: React.FunctionComponent<React.PropsWithChildren<{}>> = (props) => {
    const { currentUser } = useCurrentUser();
  
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }} {...props} />
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you, beyond awesome response =) Got to love these replies which teach you how to fish instead of just giving you the sardine, really opened my eyes about how to look at these issues. Would you recommend the complex method over the simple due to being a more specific typing? Or both are equally ok?

Comment: I'd usually opt for the second method as in any situation where the base type (`ProviderProps`) has more than the React default `children` prop you would be manually recreating a type with a possibly large amount of properties. Manually typing and not using `Omit` and the base type would be better if you wanted a loose coupling between your wrapping component and the component within, this would allow you to swap out the inner component and apply some mapping logic between your props and the internal component props (i.e. swapping third party libraries for a similar task).

Comment: playground reports error, cannot make it work in my solution either

Comment: @sKopheK that's not very descriptive, I took a quick look anyway. All I could see is an issue because of React 18 updating the `FunctionComponent` types. Here is a [rough example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-agc4xt?file=App.tsx) of both methods being perfectly happy without type errors (the link probably won't stay around forever).

Comment: @JacobSmit as I fiercelly tried all possible solutions found around the internets, I don't really remember what the issue was, but I'm glad you found some time to update your answer and fix the playground example (y)